# How to plot data on a basemap using matplotlib basemap

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

Two sections of my code are giving me trouble, I am trying to get the basemap created in this first section here:

```
#Basemap
epsg = 6060; width = 2000.e3; height = 2000.e3 #epsg 3413. 6062
m=Basemap(epsg=epsg,resolution='l',width=width,height=height) #lat_ts=(90.+35.)/2.
m.drawcoastlines(color='white')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#99ffff')
m.fillcontinents(color='#cc9966',lake_color='#99ffff')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10,70,20),labels=[1,1,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-100,0,20),labels=[0,0,0,1])
plt.title('ICESAT2 Tracks in Greenland')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
```

Then my next section is meant to plot the data its getting from a file, and plot these tracks on top of the Basemap. Instead, it creates a new plot entirely. I have tried rewording the secondary plt.scatter to match Basemap, such as m.scatter, m.plt, etc. But it only returns with “RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure” when I do so.
Any ideas on how to get this next section of code onto the basemap? Here is the next section, focus on the end to see where it is plotting.

```
icesat2_data[track] = dict() # creates a sub-dictionary, track
    icesat2_data[track][year+month+day] = dict() # and one layer more for the date under the whole icesat2_data dictionary
    icesat2_data[track][year+month+day] = dict.fromkeys(lasers)
    for laser in lasers: # for loop, access all the gt1l, 2l, 3l
        if laser in f:    
            lat = f[laser]["land_ice_segments"]["latitude"][:] # data for a particular laser's latitude.
            lon = f[laser]["land_ice_segments"]["longitude"][:] #data for a lasers longitude
            height = f[laser]["land_ice_segments"]["h_li"][:] # data for a lasers height
            quality = f[laser]["land_ice_segments"]["atl06_quality_summary"][:].astype('int')
        
                # Quality filter
            idx1 = quality == 0 # data dictionary to see what quality summary is
            #print('idx1', idx1)
        
                # Spatial filter
            idx2 = np.logical_and( np.logical_and(lat>=lat_min, lat<=lat_max), np.logical_and(lon>=lon_min, lon<=lon_max) )
        
            idx = np.where( np.logical_and(idx1, idx2) ) # combines index 1 and 2 from data quality filter. make sure not empty. if empty all data failed test (low quality or outside box)

            icesat2_data[track][year+month+day][laser] = dict.fromkeys(['lat','lon','height']) #store data, creates empty dictionary of lists lat, lon, hi, those strings are the keys to the dict.
            icesat2_data[track][year+month+day][laser]['lat'] = lat[idx] # grabbing only latitudes using that index of points with good data quality and within bounding box
            icesat2_data[track][year+month+day][laser]['lon'] = lon[idx] 
            icesat2_data[track][year+month+day][laser]['height'] = height[idx]
         
            if lat[idx].any() == True and lon[idx].any() == True:
                x, y = transformer.transform(icesat2_data[track][year+month+day][laser]['lon'], \
                                        icesat2_data[track][year+month+day][laser]['lat']) 

                plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', color='#000000')
```

Currently, they output separately, like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The statement `plt.scatter()` creates new plot. You must use `m.scatter()` to continue plotting on the same map.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still working on this, but here's a quick example I put together that you might be able to work with (obviously I don't have the data you're working with). A couple things that might not be self-explanatory - I used m() to transform the coordinates to map coordinates. This is Basemap's built-in transformation method so you don't have to use PyProj. Also, setting a zorder in the scatter function ensures that your points are plotted above the countries layer and don't get hidden underneath.

```
#Basemap

epsg = 6060; width = 2000.e3; height = 2000.e3 #epsg 3413. 6062
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
m=Basemap(epsg=epsg,resolution='l',width=width,height=height) #lat_ts=(90.+35.)/2.
m.drawcoastlines(color='white')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#99ffff')
m.fillcontinents(color='#cc9966',lake_color='#99ffff')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10,70,20),labels=[1,1,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-100,0,20),labels=[0,0,0,1])
plt.title('ICESAT2 Tracks in Greenland')


for coord in [[68,-39],[70,-39]]:
    lat = coord[0]
    lon = coord[1]
    x, y = m(lon,lat)
    m.scatter(x,y,color='red',s=100,zorder=10)
              
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need:

```
plt.figure(figsize(20,10))
```

before creating the basemap, not after. As it stands it's creating a map and then creating a new figure after that which is why you're getting two figures.

Then your plotting line should be m.scatter() as you mentioned you tried before.

Comment: Thanks! That didn't quite solve the issue. But now the figsize line makes the basemap larger. But the second one doesn't appear anymore. So At the very least that was why it went to a new graph. Now to solve why the other code isn't appearing on the same location here